# What methods of creating 'dynamic MDX' are easiest for debugging in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, ssas, mdx

I've just inherited some reports that appear to do the following:

In the dataset, there is a call to
 `code.getmymdx(dateparam, anotherparam, blahblahparam,...)`

In the code there is then a series of loops and god knows what to construct the ensuing MDX statement.

So far I've found the only way to 'see' the MDX is to put an expression in a textbox which is the same i.e.

```
 = code.getmymdx(datep...
```

Surely there is a better way of passing things to SSAS?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, they say that master coders write code that writes code but in this case I think it's overkill. 
There may be legitimate business rules being enforced by the Code.getmymdx() function but if it's just a fancy way to recursively construct an MDX statement then it sounds like it was just a fun project for a clever but bored coder. Not so useful in practice for exactly the reason you've outlined - how do you see the query text?

Admittedly, MDX is a difficult language to write, but there is an inbuilt tool in SSRS to write MDX queries visually. It also lets you create calculated members so it's a good place to start before diving into the mdx and doing manual edits.
Create a data source connection to "Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services" and then when you create a dataset and edit the query it will connect to the cube and let you drag & drop fields, as well as create parameters, filters and as I stated already calculations.

In some cases and for various reasons (e.g. combining multiple data sources), I've resorted to using stored procedures with inline MDX in them for some reports. I often still start with the automatic tool for creating MDX before diving in and manually editing it. The SQL Server that holds the stored proc has a linked server connection to the SSAS instance and uses Openquery() in dynamic SQL. 
Complicated but at least your stored procs are all in one manageable place.

Comment: Typically the statements are:  some hardcoded MDX, a bunch of loops to build up another section of MDX, some hardcoded MDX, maybe some more loops, some HC MDX. There is no 'business logic'